# Split long string of addresses into list of addresses in Python

Tags: python

I have a string of a couple thousand addresses in python, like such:

`'123 Chestnut Way 4567 Oak Lane 890 South Pine Court'`

What is the easiest way to split this long string into separate addresses? I'm trying to write a program that splits based on 3 or 4 characters in a row where `47 < ord(i) < 58`, but I'm having trouble.

Comment: Can you share a portion of the string with two to three addresses in it, so we can see how they're joined?

Comment: @TheSoundDefense It looks like they did, I think there are three addresses in there. Do you have control over where this string comes from? If so, adding *any* kind of delemeter, like a `','`, would make this a lot easier.

Comment: Yea it looks like it, now that I take a second look. If you know that all the addresses are going to have a certain format (such as `number word word`), you probably want to use regular expressions. https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: This is bound to fail. What happens when the address is "123 1 Road"? or "123 42nd Street" or "123 Route 1"?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming all of the addresses are like those given, you can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> from re import findall
>>> string = '123 Chestnut Way 4567 Oak Lane 890 South Pine Court'
>>> findall("\d+\D+(?=\s\d|$)", string)
['123 Chestnut Way', '4567 Oak Lane', '890 South Pine Court']
>>>
```

All of the Regex syntax used above is explained [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), but below is a quick breakdown:

```
\d+   # One or more digits
\D+   # One or more non-digits
(?=   # The start of a lookahead assertion
\s    # A space
\d|$  # A digit or the end of the string
)     # The end of the lookahead assertion
```

Comment: This will fail in the case of a P.O. box, if that's a concern. It will get attached to the preceding address, rather than to the one it belongs to.

Comment: @aruisdante Well the original question made it seem like addresses will always start with numbers, or at least that's what they assume.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense mm I agree, I'm more pointing that out for the OP's benefit so they can clarify if that's a problem.

Comment: It also fails for street addresses where the street name is a number.

Comment: @aruisdante - Yes, I'll admit this solution isn't very robust.  Parsing addresses is _very_ difficult because practically anything can constitute a valid address.  I just wanted to give a solution that will work for normal, simple addresses.  After all, it is better than nothing. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with regular expressions fairly easily,

```
import re
txt = '123 Chestnut Way 4567 Oak Lane 890 South Pine Court'
re.findall( r'\d+', txt )
```

the last will return all runs of digits,

```
['123', '4567', '890']
```

you can then use that information to parse the string.  there are lots of ways, but you could just find the index of the numbers in the original string and get the text in between.  you could also make the regeular expression a little more advanced. The following will match any number of digits followed by a space followed by any number of non-digits (including spaces)

```
re.findall( r'\d+ \D+', txt )
```

and will return,

```
['123 Chestnut Way ', '4567 Oak Lane ', '890 South Pine Court']
```